# WHERE clause on one field

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to create a query where the WHERE clauses only affects one field and no the others.

Sample Table:

```
+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| ID     | Name    | COUNTRY     | LANG        |
+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1      | Sami    | UK          | English     |
| 2      | James   | Spain       | NULL        |
| 3      | John    | USA         | English     |
| 4      | Alex    | Greece      | NULL        |
| 5      | Jane    | Italy       | Italian     |
+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to create a query where all
1) Count of all the ID's
2) Count of all the ID's where the LANG `IS NOT NULL`

Desired Results:

ID_Count

```
    +----------+----------------+
    | ID_COUNT | NOT_NULL_LANG  | 
    +----------+----------------+
    | 5        | 3              |
    +----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I assume my edit is a valid one.

Comment: Hey Daniel, KevinKirkpatrick's answer is the one you should accept. It doesn't  complicate things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should simply be:

```
select count(id) id_count, count(lang) NOT_NULL_LANG FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

- The COUNT() function, like most all SQL aggregation functions, excludes NULL from calculations

Comment: You where too fast for me here! I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Good answer!     .   .

Comment: Hah - by 15 seconds if my refresh was right :-).  Thought I was beat to the punch, but realized the other responses were overlooking the more direct approach... seemed a good opportunity to share the handy knowledge that, per SQL standards, nearly all aggregation functions ignore NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNT`, `ISNULL` and `SUM` functions.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS ID_COUNT,
COUNT(ID)-SUM(IFNULL(LANG, 1)) AS NOT_NULL_LANG 
FROM yourtable
```

Output

```
ID_COUNT    NOT_NULL_LANG
5           3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/458c9/6/0

Comment: Seems like a laborious way of expressing the sentiment.